# Grafana Tempo is not able to connect with Azure Container Storage Backend

Tags: azure, trace, tempo, grafana-tempo

I am using **grafana-tempo** helm chart and want to set up its backend with **azure container storage**.

I have a **client environment** where the **k8s cluster** is running and they have some policy restrictions as they have set up **Kyverno** in the backend.

I'm giving all the required configurations but my **grafana-tempo** **pods** are not getting up and throwing continuously below error.

```
ERROR:

msg="error running Tempo" err="failed to init module services error initialising module: store: failed to create store failed to GetProperties: Get \"https://<AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME>.blob.core.windows.net/<AZURE_CONTAINER_NAME>?restype=container&timeout=61\": EOF"
```

Here is the **storage** code block written in **tempo**:

```
storage:
  trace:
    block:
      version: vParquet
    backend: azure
    azure:
      container_name: <my_container_name>
      storage_account_name: <my_storage_account_name>
      storage_account_key: <my_storage_account_key>
  admin:
    backend: azure
```

**Note:** I have tried the similar setup in my **personal AKS** and the implementation is working really **fine**.
But In the **client environment**, its not working due to to some restrictions (I guess).

**Expectation:** Our **grafana-tempo** in **client environment** should succesfully **connect** to **azure container backend** and it should run **smoothly**.

**Q1.** Does someone have faced the same issue and have something regarding it?

**Q2.** Is there any parameters available to directly give the **Azure Container URL** in the above **storage block** section so that it should directly fetch from that?
I was going through this doc for azure backend but can't find any parameter which takes **Container URL** as an input
https://grafana.com/docs/tempo/latest/configuration/

*Thanks in advance!*